# Hierarchical import single query solution - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, hierarchical-data, connect-by

I have a interesting problem, at least I think so.
So, I have a table (codes_table) with the above structure (it is a tree menu)
the tree is defined by two integers plus a dot pattern (always) like this:

```
COD_MENU               NAME
01.                 Biggest Node
01.01.              Sun of 01.
01.01.01.           Sun of 01.01.
01.01.01.01.        Sun of 01.01.01.
01.01.01.02.        Sun of 01.01.01.
01.01.01.03.        Sun of 01.01.01.
01.01.01.04.        Sun of 01.01.01.
01.01.01.05.        Sun of 01.01.01.
01.02.              Sun of 01.
01.03.              Sun of 01.
01.03.01.           Sun of 01.03.
(etc...)
```

What I need is to generate insert scripts to a new table with a structure with numeric 
IDs with foreing key to its father putting the actual COD_MENU as name on the
new structure like this:

```
ID     FATHER_ID         NAME 
1        NULL            01.
2        1               01.01.
3        2               01.01.01.
4        3               01.01.01.01.
5        3               01.01.01.02.
6        3               01.01.01.03.
7        3               01.01.01.04.
8        3               01.01.01.05.
9        1               01.02.
10       1               01.03.
11       10              01.03.01.
```

I already did this in a plsql block code with a recursive procedure. 
Above is my real code for reference.

```
declare
   auxId integer;

   procedure findNodes( pCod varchar2, pCurrId in out integer, pFatherId in integer  ) is
        ctHasSuns integer; 
        father    varchar2(20);
        idFhtTmp     integer;
     begin

        idFhtTmp  := pFatherId;

        if idFhtTmp is null then
            father := 'null';
        else
            father := idFhtTmp;
        end if;
        ctHasSuns := 0;

        SELECT count(cod_menu) into ctHasSuns FROM codes_table where SUBSTR (cod_menu, 1,LENGTH (cod_menu) - 3) = pCod and rownum < 10;

        if (ctHasSuns > 0 or pCurrId = 1) then
            dbms_output.put_line ('insert into newtable ( id, idfather, menu ) values ( '||pCurrId||','||father||', '''||pCod||''' );');
            idFhtTmp := pCurrId;
            for cHasSuns in ( SELECT cod_menu FROM codes_table where SUBSTR (cod_menu, 1,LENGTH (cod_menu) - 3) = pCod and rownum < 10 order by cod_menu) loop
                pCurrId := pCurrId + 1;
                findNodes( cHasSuns.cod_menu, pCurrId, idFhtTmp );
            end loop;
        else
            dbms_output.put_line ('insert into newtable ( id, idfather, menu ) values ( '||pCurrId||','||father||', '''||pCod||''' );');
        end if;

     end;

begin
  auxId := 1;
  findNodes( '01.', auxId, null );
end;
```

What I'm trying to do is acomplish that in a single query using CONNECT BY / START WITH / ROWNUM and 
LEVEL statments and usign joins with the same table if necessary. I tryied a lot of things and couldn't
came out with a solution. This is just for curiosity.

The closest thing I could do is the select above but I just have the ID for the father not the suns

```
WITH q AS (
select rownum id, father  from (
select a.noh father, count(*) 
from (select cod_menu noh, substr( cod_menu, 1, length(cod_menu)-3) as nofather from codes_table) a,
     (select cod_menu noh, substr( cod_menu, 1, length(cod_menu)-3) as nofather from codes_table) b
where a.noh = b.nofather
group by a.noh
having count(*) > 0 
order by a.noh)
), 
b as (
 SELECT cod_menu filho, father
  FROM (select cod_menu, substr( cod_menu, 1, length(cod_menu)-3) as father from codes_table)
  START WITH father is null
CONNECT BY prior cod_menu = father 
  ORDER BY cod_menu
)
SELECT * FROM q, b where q.father = b.father;
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution:

```
CREATE TABLE codes_table (
  cod_menu VARCHAR2(40),
  name VARCHAR2(40)
);

INSERT INTO codes_table VALUES ('01.', 'Biggest Node');
INSERT INTO codes_table VALUES ('01.01.', 'Sun of 01.');
INSERT INTO codes_table VALUES ('01.01.01.', 'Sun of 01.01.');
INSERT INTO codes_table VALUES ('01.01.01.01.', 'Sun of 01.01.01.');
INSERT INTO codes_table VALUES ('01.01.01.02.', 'Sun of 01.01.01.');
INSERT INTO codes_table VALUES ('01.01.01.03.', 'Sun of 01.01.01.');
INSERT INTO codes_table VALUES ('01.01.01.04.', 'Sun of 01.01.01.');
INSERT INTO codes_table VALUES ('01.01.01.05.', 'Sun of 01.01.01.');
INSERT INTO codes_table VALUES ('01.02.', 'Sun of 01.');
INSERT INTO codes_table VALUES ('01.03.', 'Sun of 01.');
INSERT INTO codes_table VALUES ('01.03.01.', 'Sun of 01.03.');

COMMIT;

SELECT
    id,
    PRIOR id AS father_id,
    cod_menu AS name
  FROM (
    SELECT
      cod_menu,
      name,
      row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cod_menu) AS id
    FROM
      codes_table
)
START WITH cod_menu = '01.'
CONNECT BY SUBSTR(cod_menu, 1, LENGTH(cod_menu) - 3) = PRIOR cod_menu
;
```

Check at SQLFiddle: [Fiddle with it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9887e/2)

Comment: Man, I'm applauding you!! I've heard about this OVER but I didn't know how to use it! Thank you so much.